# What is the "Typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined" meaning?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm new to google appscript and Javascript.:)

I want to know why the following error keep occurring when executing?

Can you guys help and purpose me a solution for this?

Thanks

`enter code here`

```js
var previousDataRange = ss2.getRange(5,1,lastRow,8);
 
  previousDataRange.clear();

  var data = ss.getRange(3,1,lastRow-1,8).getValues();
   
  var currentRow = ss2.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  for (var a =  0 ; a <=data.length ; a++){
   
    for(var b = 0 ; b <=7 ; b++){  // 8 Columns
  
      var cellValue = data[a][b]; //I got the error "typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined" here
      
      ss2.getRange(currentRow,b+1).setValue(cellValue);
    }
        currentRow = currentRow + 1;
    }
```

Comment: it means the array variable is not defined. So you cannot access var[0]

Comment: value of data is undefined;

Comment: `console.log(data[a])` before accessing it

Comment: Can someone give me the updated code??? Super thanks:)

Comment: use the first for loop with a <data.length

Comment: Problem solved , thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In arrays indexes start from 0 so you need to loop to length-1.
Do the same with b

```js
var previousDataRange = ss2.getRange(5,1,lastRow,8);
 
  previousDataRange.clear();

  var data = ss.getRange(3,1,lastRow-1,8).getValues();
   
  var currentRow = ss2.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  for (var a =  0 ; a <data.length ; a++){
   
    for(var b = 0 ; b <=7 ; b++){  // 8 Columns
  
      var cellValue = data[a][b]; //I got the error "typeerror cannot read property '0' of undefined" here
      
      ss2.getRange(currentRow,b+1).setValue(cellValue);
    }
        currentRow = currentRow + 1;
    }
```